# Error in Casting date postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I'm trying to cast a varchar into a date with this following code, and the following error is outputting, any idea why?

```
ALTER TABLE import.employee
ALTER COLUMN birth_date
TYPE date
USING (birth_date::date);
```

---

```
    ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "05/29/1960"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "05/29/1960"
SQL state: 22008
Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the datestyle before:

```
set datestyle = mdy;
```

Comment: Or `using (to_date(birth_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))` if you don't want to mess around with or worry about connection settings.

Comment: Worked like a charm Clodoaldo :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get the ::date from birth_date, first give the DATE format to your field using the given functions in [Data Type Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) docs.